# How do I checkout from a branch using Git if I haven't told it where to look?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to checkout a certain branch from a Github project, but I don't know how to tell Git (in the terminal) what project I am using. I have cloned the project to my computer but when I run `git checkout NAME`, it says this `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

What does this mean? What command do I run to tell it that I want the branch from the specific project?

Comment: How did you clone the project? Did you use git clone command ?

Comment: yes I did, but I have been using Git with another project before i started this one. does this matter?

Comment: As long as folders are different, it shouldn't matter... make sure you are inside the project folder and run the command git checkout there

Comment: Did you remember to `cd` into the clone folder? No kidding, I always forget that step.

Comment: To prove you are in the right place, say `ls -al`. You should see `.git` among the files. If you don't, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: I created a folder, cd into that and then git cloned it. That's correct right?

Comment: Nope. You now need to cd into the folder that came down from the network.

Comment: Wow that was why. I feel dumb, I have never done this before so thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, like I say, I always forget this too, and I've been doing it for years and years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps I follow are like this:

1. `cd Desktop` (or wherever I want to work)
2. `git clone <whatever>` (notice that I did *not* need to make a folder; `git clone` will do that)
3. `cd whatever` (move into the folder that git created)
4. `git status` (if git is happy about my saying that, we're ready to rock and roll)

By the way, a great trick is `cd; find . -name .git -type d -prune` which (at the cost of some time) prints out the pathnames of all the git repositories on your computer. To work in one of them, `cd` into it without the `/.git`. For example, if you see `./Desktop/testinggit/.git`, then say `cd ./Desktop/testinggit`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are outsider of the local directory where the project is cloned.

```
cd dir-to-project
```

Then it should work

Comment: I am in the project directory. Could it be that I need to add remote origin? I am not sure what that does..

Answer (score 0):

To perform git commands, you must `cd` to a directory that contains a git repository. The easiest way to do that is immediately after you execute `git clone`. Here is an example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/my_user/my_repo.git
$ cd my_repo
$ git checkout new-branch
```

`git clone` creates a new folder named `my_repo` in the current folder. This `my_repo` folder is your project folder. Replace `my_user` with your user name and `my_repo` with the repository that you are cloning.